# PhantomJs not working in linux for jasmine testing using karma tool AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am using karma for my jasmine testing.

I am using phantomJs browser to run the test cases.

It's working fine in windows but not in linux.

But the problem is we work on windows but our website is deployed in linux.

Below is my karma.config.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (config) {
  var browsers = require('os').platform() === 'win32' ? ['Chrome'] : ['PhantomJS'];
  config.set({
    browsers: browsers,
    frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
    singleRun: true,
    files: [
      { pattern: 'dist/*.js', watched: false },
      'test/prb.test.js',
      'test/mock/*.js',
      { pattern: 'test/data/**/*.json', included: false },
      { pattern: 'test/spec/**/*.js', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'dist/*.js': ['coverage']
    },
    reporters: [
      'coverage',
      'spec'
    ],
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,
      suppressErrorSummary: true,
      suppressFailed: false,
      suppressPassed: true,
      suppressSkipped: true
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        { type: 'text' },
        { type: 'cobertura' }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

This is working fine in windows but I get error in linux.
Below is snapshot of error in linux.

[image: Error in linux]